# Apply a function every 60 rows in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, mapreduce

My dataframe is called df, has 123729 rows, and looks like this:

```
+---+------+------+
| HR|maxABP|Second|
+---+------+------+
|110| 128.0|     1|
|110| 127.0|     2|
|111| 127.0|     3|
|111| 127.0|     4|
|111| 126.0|     5|
|111| 127.0|     6|
|109| 126.0|     7|
|111| 126.0|     8|
```

I need to aggregate every 60 rows, or seconds, to multiple values. For every minute, I want to know the minimal heartrate, the average heartrate, the maximal heartrate, and if maxABP was below 85 in any of those seconds. The desired output would look something like the table below, where Alarm is 1 if maxABP < 85, otherwise 0.

| Min_HR | Max_HR | Avg_HR | Alarm | Minute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70 | 100 | 80 | 1 | 1 |
| 60 | 90 | 75 | 0 | 2 |

I'm wondering if it's possible to use mapreduce to aggregate every 60 rows to these single values. I know there is a lot wrong, but maybe something like this:

```
def max_HR(df, i):
   x = i
   y = i+60
   return reduce(lambda x, y: max(df[x:y]))

df_maxHR = map(lambda i: max_HR(i))
```

Where `i` should be parts of the df.

Comment: Add more sample data. is there a minute col, or the second col goes over 60 like 61, 62 and so on?

Comment: All the sample data look like that. No more columns, and seconds keep going to 123729

Comment: Also, how this DF is getting populated? by Streaming? Always a fixed number of 123729 rows?

Comment: Could you when parallelizing the data do so in 60 row partitions rather than using the default value? `sc.parallelize(<my_data>, <num_rows>%60)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `groupBy` is enough to get the required result.

```py
df.show()
+---+------+------+
| HR|maxABP|Second|
+---+------+------+
|110| 128.0|    10|
|110| 127.0|    20|
|111| 127.0|    30|
|111| 127.0|    40|
|111| 126.0|    50|
|111| 127.0|    60|
|109| 126.0|    70|
|111| 126.0|    80|
+---+------+------+

df.withColumn('Minute', f.expr('cast(Second / 60 as int)')) \
  .groupBy('Minute').agg( \
    f.round(f.min('HR'), 2).alias('Min_HR'), \
    f.round(f.max('HR'), 2).alias('Max_HR'), \
    f.round(f.avg('HR'), 2).alias('Avg_HR'), \
    f.max('maxABP').alias('maxABP')) \
  .withColumn('Alarm', f.expr('if(maxABP < 85, 1, 0)')) \
  .show()

+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
|Minute|Min_HR|Max_HR|Avg_HR|maxABP|Alarm|
+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
|     1|   109|   111|110.33| 127.0|    0|
|     0|   110|   111| 110.6| 128.0|    0|
+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
```

Comment: Yes this is the way how I solved it eventually, thanks for your reply.
I got the minutes column by using: withColumn('Minute', F.ceil(df_filtered['Second'] / 60))

Answer (score 2):

Exemple DF:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
     (110, 128.0, 1),(110, 127.0, 2),(111, 127.0, 3),(111, 127.0, 4)
    ,(111, 126.0, 5),(111, 127.0, 6),(109, 126.0, 7),(111, 126.0, 1001)
    ,(114, 126.0, 1003),(115, 83.0, 1064),(116, 127.0, 1066)
  ], ['HR', 'maxABP', 'Second']
)

+---+------+------+
| HR|maxABP|Second|
+---+------+------+
|110| 128.0|     1|
|110| 127.0|     2|
|111| 127.0|     3|
|111| 127.0|     4|
|111| 126.0|     5|
|111| 127.0|     6|
|109| 126.0|     7|
|111| 126.0|  1001|
|114| 126.0|  1003|
|115|  83.0|  1064|
|116| 127.0|  1066|
```

Then using window functions:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w1 = (Window.partitionBy(F.col('Minute')))

df\
  .withColumn('Minute', F.round(F.col('Second')/60,0)+1)\
  .withColumn('Min_HR', F.min('HR').over(w1))\
  .withColumn('Max_HR', F.max('HR').over(w1))\
  .withColumn('Avg_HR', F.round(F.avg('HR').over(w1),0))\
  .withColumn('Min_ABP', F.round(F.min('maxABP').over(w1),0))\
  .select('Min_HR','Max_HR','Min_ABP','Avg_HR','Minute')\
  .dropDuplicates()\
  .withColumn('Alarm', F.when(F.col('Min_ABP')<85, 1).otherwise(F.lit('0')))\
  .select('Min_HR','Max_HR','Avg_HR','Alarm','Minute')\
  .orderBy('Minute')\
  .show()

+------+------+------+-----+------+
|Min_HR|Max_HR|Avg_HR|Alarm|Minute|
+------+------+------+-----+------+
|   109|   111| 110.0|    0|   1.0|
|   111|   114| 113.0|    0|  18.0|
|   115|   116| 116.0|    1|  19.0|
```